# Need help adding plane to be on a line

Tags: html, css

I had initially had the design as a content value in css but tried changing it to be its own div and testing to see if it's a structure issue. I just need the plane to be exactly on the very end of the thicker part of the line.

Image of how painfully close it is:
[image]

```css
#two {
  background-size: 100%;
  background-image: linear-gradient(to right, #ffffff, #000000);
  margin-right: 200px;
  margin-left: 80px;
  overflow: visible;
  height: 1px;
  padding: 0.0em 0.0em 0.0em 0.0em;
  border-bottom: 10px;
}

.divider {
  border: 1em 1em 1em 1em;
  padding: 1em 1em 1em 1em;
}

.plane {
  padding: 0.5em 0.5em 0.5em 0.5em;
  margin-left: 1150px;
  margin-bottom: 100px;
}
```

```html
<div class="divider">
  <div id="two"></div>
  <div class="plane">✈</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```css
#two {
  background-size: 100%;
  background-image: linear-gradient(to right, #ffffff, #000000);
  margin-right: 200px;
  margin-left: 80px;
  overflow: visible;
  height: 1px;
  padding: 0.0em 0.0em 0.0em 0.0em;
  border-bottom: 10px;
}

.divider {
  position: relative;
}

.plane {
  position: absolute;
  top: -.7rem;
  right: 12rem;
  margin-left: 0;
  margin-right: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="divider">
  <div id="two"></div>
  <div class="plane">✈</div>
</div>
```

Comment: @mplungjan then what you edited on this? only `padding`

Comment: I just put it in a snippet so we can see if it works. Please leave it in a snippet. It works now

Comment: Thank you for the help, this had resolved the issue.

Answer (score 4):

```css
#two {
  background-size: 100%;
  background-image: linear-gradient(to right, #ffffff, #000000);
  overflow: visible;
  height: 1px;
  padding: 0;
  border-bottom: 10px;
}

.divider {
  position: relative;
  padding: 1em;
  margin-top: 70px;
}

.plane {
  position: absolute;
  top: -1px;
  right: 0;
  padding: 0.5em;
  bottom: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="divider">
  <div id="two"></div>
  <div class="plane">✈</div>
</div>
```

Comment: This is so weird. Chrome on Windows on a large screen is perfect, Chrome on OSX is half a pixel off on a large screen. Chrome on Windows with a small laptop is 2 pixels off

Comment: That is odd but the code is still good thank you for the help.

Answer (score 0):

**The simple thing** you can do is just add `position: absolute;` and `Top: 4px;` on `.plane`

```css
#two {
  background-size: 100%;
  background-image: linear-gradient(to right, #ffffff, #000000);
  margin-right: 200px;
  margin-left: 80px;
  overflow: visible;
  height: 1px;
  padding: 0.0em 0.0em 0.0em 0.0em;
  border-bottom: 10px;
}

.divider {
  border: 1em 1em 1em 1em;
  padding: 1em 1em 1em 1em;
}

.plane {
  padding: 0.5em;
  margin-left: 1145px;
  margin-bottom: 100px;
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  margin-right: 200px;
  top: 4.3px;
}
```

```html
<div class="divider">
  <div id="two"></div>
  <div class="plane">✈</div>
</div>
```

Comment: @mplungjan you wanted an answer to center the plane did you got that. Anyways I am copying snippet to answer for your convenience

Comment: @mplungjan Glad to help you out !!

Comment: @mplungjan oh yeh . Sorry I forgot to add position: absolute; . My bad

Comment: Did you opened it on full screen

Comment: That's what you wanted right

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/238081/discussion-between-krishna-noutiyal-and-mplungjan).

Comment: Sure now see it is working right

Comment: oh ye i am in chrome actually and it look fine in it

Comment: How is it possible it is just looking gorgeous in chrome

Comment: Nope. Compare to this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/69550105/295783

Comment: Thank you so much for the help on this!